# Get distinct values from a comma-delimited column and insert in another table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I  have a column in a MySQL table that consists of comma-separated values in a column and there various duplicate values in the same column. data look like below-

`select id,category_ids from tableName;
+---------+-----------------------+
| id      | category_ids          |
+---------+-----------------------+
| 1062810 | 4,7,2,2,2,2,4,7       |
| 1062812 | 4                     |
| 1062814 | 7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7       |
| 1062850 | 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2 |
| 1063294 | 6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6 |`

and Out put should be

`+---------+-----------------------+
| id      | category_ids          |
+---------+-----------------------+
| 1062810 | 4,7,2                 |
| 1062812 | 4                     |
| 1062814 | 7                     |
| 1062850 | 2                     |
| 1063294 | 6                     |`

Please help me out I'm new to mysql

Comment: if any one can put and update query for the above will be more help full for me

Comment: May I know which is your server side scripting language? Ex: PHP

Comment: Hi @MathsRkBala I am using PHP

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "select id,category_ids from tableName";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id = $row["id"];
        $category_ids = array_unique(explode(',',$row["category_ids"]));

        $update_sql = "update tableName category_ids='".implode($category_ids,',')."' where id = ".$id ;
        $res = $conn->query($update_sql,$conn);

        echo "Update ID-".$id." Category ids:" .$row["category_ids"]. " Into " . implode($category_ids,','). "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "No data in your table";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Thanks @Maths this can be a good solution, but i am looking for some mysql query solution.